# How to set locale to child locals (e.g. en-GB, en-US or fr-CA) with locales in react-intl v2

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I am trying to use `react-intl` in order to localise a react app.

It is set up and works with all parent locales such as `EN`, `DE`, `FR` etc. I can view the child locales such as `en-GB` and `en-US`, however, I cannot display them in the browser.

This is how I am importing the locale at the moment:

`import en from 'react-intl/locale-data/en';`

I would expect `react-intl` to be able to go into the child locale automatically, is this not the case?

Any help welcome!

Answer (score 1):

It should be worked. do you use `addLocaleData`?

https://codesandbox.io/s/reactintl-formattedtime-s09vo?fontsize=14

Comment: Yes, I add the locale data using `addLocaleData` as such: 

`import en from 'react-intl/locale-data/en';
import { addLocaleData } from 'react-intl';

import localEn from '../en.json';

addLocaleData([ ...en, ...de, ...fr]);
`

The issue is with getting the child locales from the `react-intl/locales/en.js` file.

Comment: I thought just `import en from 'react-intl/locale-data/en'` is enough to load locale for child locales as I put on the codesandbox. May I ask how you cannot display in the browser? Or the issue is you want to get child locale from `react-intl/locales/en.js`?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped I meant in the child locales `react-intl/locale-data/en` file. 

I was mistaken though, the issue was that I wasn't pointing to the correct local/user made locale files for child locales. 

What I did was map it so that `en` would also be used for `en-GB`, `en-US` (pointing to the local `en.json` and then for specific regions I have it pointing to the child locals such as 'fr-CA' points to a local 'fr-CA.json' for the translations.

Thank you very much for your help @banyan